# Format Line not actually formatting.

Tags: c#, resharper, stylecop

I have Resharper 9 installed and StyleCop as I'm trialling then to see if my work should get the tools installed for all developers (So I'm very new to using both tools).

StyleCop has a number of rules that affect line formatting, such as:  SA1116. Resharper then picks up when these rules are violated and it offers the option to have it automatically fixed (as you can see below).

[image]

The only problem is when I actually hit enter nothing happens. Well nothing happens 80% of the time for this rule violation as well as for a bunch of the other formatting issues such as a space between a cast and a variable (e.g. `(double) myDouble;`)

It seems so erratic, does anybody know how to improve this or is it simply credit to StyleCop not completely integrating with Resharper? (In which case should I stop looking at recharper/stylecop combo as a "press button to fix" tool and more like "here's a warning, your welcome. Now if there's a button, press it you're lucky")

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be worth raising this as an issue with the [StyleCop project on CodePlex](https://stylecop.codeplex.com). However, the CodePlex project seems to be a bit abandoned - the current ReSharper 9 plugin is provided by a community member. There's a GitHub repo (although it doesn't have source) that you could use to try and [file an issue](https://github.com/kubiix/ReSharper.StyleCop/issues).

Comment: Filed an issue here: https://github.com/kubiix/ReSharper.StyleCop/issues/5

However, I won't accept your answer just yet as I want to leave it up a bit longer to see if anybody else comes up with a fix.